# How to format mysql between date Query in javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

i want to get data between two dates in experss js javascript below is my query

```
 period = ` created_datetime BETWEEN ` + fromdate + ` AND ` + todate;
```

but getting error like below
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00 AND
2021-02-20 23:59:59

Comment: the error message say 'near '00:00:00 AND 2021-02-20 23:59:59' it looks like fromdate is equal 00:00:00

Comment: Where are the single quote?

Comment: @jeremy no the error is because of missing quotes. MySQL has no issues if date contain `00:00` or some other time part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is missing single quotes around the data you inject through the script, so MySQL tries to interpret your dates as everything else than string data.

Try this:

```
 const period = `created_datetime BETWEEN '${fromdate}' AND '${todate}'`;
```

If you are already using backticks, have a look at [ES6 Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like I used them in the example above.